# eth.getTransactionReceipt fails to return transaction receipt in local Ethereum network

Tags: ethereum, web3js, go-ethereum

I have setup a local network running with bootnode,node1,node2,signer node
When I sent transaction from geth js console, I am able to see the receipt immediately:

> > eth.getTransactionReceipt("0x1858f9b411d75b76ac5c91bb2d5edd79ba7f289ef8ac6dcce20f9f1aa9302024")
>
> {   blockHash:
> "0x41793542b33766175ade09addc238325e7167512fd2b7316cbca4f7d4ee5dee3",
> blockNumber: 982,   contractAddress: null,   cumulativeGasUsed: 21000,
> effectiveGasPrice: 1000000007,   from:
> "0xc4ffca9978011b3bd69975b51706a055424c6feb",   gasUsed: 21000,
> logs: [],   logsBloom:
>
> > "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
> > status: "0x1",   to: "0xa4c9f4d914aa525487544bfc09334aa2146e6f3c",
> > transactionHash:
> > "0x1858f9b411d75b76ac5c91bb2d5edd79ba7f289ef8ac6dcce20f9f1aa9302024",
> > transactionIndex: 0,   type: "0x2" }

However when I run it from VS code terminal

> const WS = require("ws"); const { Web3 } = require('web3');
>
> const web3 = new Web3(new
> Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://127.0.0.1:8545')); rcpt =
> web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt("0x1858f9b411d75b76ac5c91bb2d5edd79ba7f289ef8ac6dcce20f9f1aa9302024");
> console.log(rcpt);
> web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt("0x1858f9b411d75b76ac5c91bb2d5edd79ba7f289ef8ac6dcce20f9f1aa9302024",
> function(error,result){
> console.log(result);
> });

It returns following in the first call, the second call doest not print anything.

> Promise {  }

Why is it failing when I run from VS code console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `getTransactionReceipt` (just as other web3 functions) returns a `Promise`. In other words, the flow is asynchronous but your code is synchronous. You need to either wrap it in an `async` function and use the `await` keyword, or, use the `Promise.then()` approach, i.e.

```
const WS = require("ws"); const { Web3 } = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider('http://127.0.0.1:8545'));
web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt("0x1858f9b411d75b76ac5c91bb2d5edd79ba7f289ef8ac6dcce20f9f1aa9302024")
  .then(console.log);
```

For more info see the documentation at https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html#gettransactionreceipt